# Testing controllers with rspec, authenticated with Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, sorcery

We are using the [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) gem for authentication in our Rails 4 app. We want to write controller specs for our app (we are testing with Rspec), but all our methods calls in our specs are redirected as we haven't logged in to our application when running the tests.

What extra configuration changes do we need to make to allow controller specs?

**rails_helper.rb**

```
Spec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
end
```

**customers_vehicles_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CustomersVehiclesController, type: :controller do

  describe 'POST update_customer' do
    before(:each) do
    @job = create(:job)
    @vehicle = @job.vehicle
    @customer = @vehicle.customers.last
    @user = create(:user_schade)
    @now = DateTime.now

    login_user
end

context 'user has unassinged time' do
  it 'gets the vehicle information page' do
    get :show_customer, id: @customer.id

    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(action).to render_template(partial:'customer_form')
  end
end
end
```

This test fails on the get; we receive a 302 (redirect) because we are not logged in.

What configuration options are we missing be able to test our controllers?

Note: We are using Sorcery 0.8.4

Answer (score 1):

This is something I ran into. One thing that might be worth checking is what version of the sorcery gem you are using because if the version you are using is >= 0.8.6 (0.8.6 was just released a few weeks ago I think), then you would need to replace in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
```

with

```
config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller, type: :controller
config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration, type: :feature
```

as shown in [upgrading](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery#upgrading) which has more information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: On your advice we tried 0.8.6, but that version introduces login issues. Sorcery appears to use a different crypto for creating passwords and checking if they are okay when logging in, despite using default settings.
0.8.6 Also threw an error that it couldn't find Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller

Comment: https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/wiki/Testing-Rails